# How can I make a cell pin to the top of a collectionView like a header?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to implement a searchBar inside of a collectionView cell, after being unable to get the search bar to work with reloading the cells as a header, I have implemented the searchBar inside of the first dequeued cell. How can I give this cell properties similar to a sticky Header where it stays on top of the screen as the user scrolls up and hides when the user scrolls down? Is this possible thank you?

Below is the code in question

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        return cv
    }()

    var genericTagsArray:[String] = ["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","tag8","tag9","tag10","tag11","tag12","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Ab","Abc","za","tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","tag8","tag9","tag10","tag11","tag12","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Ab","Abc","za"]

    var currentTagsArray:[String] = [String]() {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        currentTagsArray = genericTagsArray

        collectionView.register(Header.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "\(Header.self)")

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentTagsArray.count + 1
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
    }

    var searchCell:Header!
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.item == 0 {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "\(Header.self)", for: indexPath) as! Header
            cell.searchBar.delegate = self
            searchCell = cell

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.currentTagsArray.count != 0 {
                    self.searchCell?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
            }

            return cell
        }

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        cell.label.text = currentTagsArray[indexPath.item - 1]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.currentTagsArray = self.genericTagsArray.filter { (text) -> Bool in
            return text.contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
    }

    var lastContentOffset:CGFloat = 0

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if self.lastContentOffset > self.collectionView.contentOffset.y  && self.collectionView.contentOffset.y > 0 && self.collectionView.contentOffset.y < collectionView.frame.maxY {

            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            searchCell.isHidden = false
        }
        else if (self.lastContentOffset < self.collectionView.contentOffset.y) && (self.collectionView.contentOffset.y < self.collectionView.frame.maxY) && (self.collectionView.contentOffset.y > 0)  {
            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            searchCell.isHidden = true
        }
        else{
            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            print("content offSet: \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
            print("Nothing happened")
            //  self.headerDelegate?.hideHeaderView(hide: true)
        }
    }


}

class Cell : UICollectionViewCell {

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .gray
        self.addSubview(label)
       label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
       label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
       label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}

class Header : UICollectionViewCell {

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .gray
        self.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        searchBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```